# In CSS, how to hover a background over an image

Tags: css

I have a simple `<img>` image on a page and I would like to show a dark background when hovered over the top of it. What sounds like something trivial seems to be something way more difficult to archive.

This is my current code. The problem that even setting a `z-index` position, the background is always placed behind the `src` image.

```
<style>
  img:hover { 
    background: black;
    z-index: 999;
  }
</style>

<img src="image.jpg" />
```

Any idea how to archive this?

Comment: "the background is always placed behind the src image." that's why it's called a background. If you want it on top of the image you need to use another element to place on top of your image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set the black background on a wrapper of the image and make the image have `opacity: 0` on hover.

## [demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/3768033)

**HTML**:

```
<div class='wrapper'><img src='image.jpg'></div>
```

Relevant **CSS**:

```
.wrapper { background: black; }
.wrapper img:hover { opacity: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of what you're trying to do, but if you want to cover the image with a black square, then you must use other object on top of it, because the background will never stop being a BACKground.